# Error Message React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm watching a tutorial video on udemy by [Stephen Grider](https://www.udemy.com/react-redux) am at section 2 talking about how to work with Props.

Error Message that getting is **'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ()'**

I have looked back at **index.js** and **video_list.js** files on the video, to make sure I had not misspelled.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

``` bundle.js:19852 Error: findComponentRoot(..., .0.0.0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables, nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG elements in an <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``. ```

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
const API_KEY = 'Youtube API Here'; // YouTube API Key

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { video: [] };

    YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'surfboards' }, (videos) => {
      // console.log(data);
      this.setState({ videos });
      // this.setState({ videos: videos }); Only work if the key var name are samething
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
        <VideoList videos={this.state.videos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

**videos_list.js**

```
import React from 'react';

  const VideoList = (props) => {
    console.log(VideoList);
      return (
          <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
              { props.videos.length }
          </ul>
      );
  };

export default VideoList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a typo, Instead of video use videos in state variable:

```
this.state = { videos: [] };
```

Comment: @MayankShula Thank you, can you vote up on my post please